# Google map is not running even if everything is right

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

i am trying to implement a Google map in my android app.Following is my code:

```
  private GoogleMap googleMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.connect);

initilizeMap();
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);



}


private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

and my xml file:

```
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Logcat error:

```
    07-24 07:27:44.636: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.636: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.646: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.656: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.656: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.676: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.676: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.676: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.686: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.686: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.686: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.686: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.686: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-24 07:27:44.686: W/AudioService(382): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-24 07:27:46.426: W/Response(1358): {"GET":[],"POST":{"action":"login","app_secret":"jkhljkUILJGJkljhkjUGLG87796587687HGKJhghkjKUYGKJHjhgjUYGKUY7865876hgKUYGK","email":"a","password":"aa"},"status":"ERROR","msg":"Sorry ! Invalid Username or Password"}
07-24 07:27:46.526: I/ActivityManager(382): START u0 {cmp=example.atlcitylimo/.Home} from pid 1358
07-24 07:27:46.686: I/Choreographer(1358): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:46.966: E/dalvikvm(1358): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment', referenced from method example.atlcitylimo.Home.initilizeMap
07-24 07:27:46.976: W/dalvikvm(1358): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 992 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;) in Lexample/atlcitylimo/Home;
07-24 07:27:46.976: D/dalvikvm(1358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000f
07-24 07:27:47.036: I/dalvikvm(1358): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMapType, referenced from method example.atlcitylimo.Home.onCreate
07-24 07:27:47.036: W/dalvikvm(1358): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8258: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap;.setMapType (I)V
07-24 07:27:47.086: D/dalvikvm(1358): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0042
07-24 07:27:47.386: D/dalvikvm(1358): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 6% free 5764K/6080K, paused 86ms, total 88ms
07-24 07:27:47.386: I/dalvikvm-heap(1358): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.048MB for 2457616-byte allocation
07-24 07:27:47.526: D/dalvikvm(1358): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 8162K/8484K, paused 138ms, total 138ms
07-24 07:27:48.956: D/AndroidRuntime(1358): Shutting down VM
07-24 07:27:48.956: W/dalvikvm(1358): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a75ba8)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): Process: example.atlcitylimo, PID: 1358
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.atlcitylimo/example.atlcitylimo.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class fragment
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at example.atlcitylimo.Home.onCreate(Home.java:45)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     ... 11 more
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     ... 22 more
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/example.atlcitylimo-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/example.atlcitylimo-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
07-24 07:27:49.056: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     ... 25 more
07-24 07:27:49.476: W/ActivityManager(382):   Force finishing activity example.atlcitylimo/.Home
07-24 07:27:49.526: W/ActivityManager(382):   Force finishing activity example.atlcitylimo/.Main
07-24 07:27:49.796: D/dalvikvm(382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 517K, 20% free 6664K/8264K, paused 132ms, total 135ms
07-24 07:27:49.796: I/dalvikvm-heap(382): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.196MB for 635812-byte allocation
07-24 07:27:49.926: D/dalvikvm(382): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 19% free 7282K/8888K, paused 134ms, total 134ms
07-24 07:27:49.936: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:50.806: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:50.976: W/ActivityManager(382): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b3fc3d40 u0 example.atlcitylimo/.Home t2 f}
07-24 07:27:51.386: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 151 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:51.496: I/Choreographer(554): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:51.516: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:51.946: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 119 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:52.406: D/dalvikvm(554): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 445K, 16% free 5555K/6564K, paused 65ms, total 70ms
07-24 07:27:52.836: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:53.096: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:53.196: I/ActivityManager(382): Killing 860:com.android.music/u0a35 (adj 15): empty #17
07-24 07:27:53.466: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:27:53.486: W/MediaFocusControl(382):   RemoteControlClient died
07-24 07:28:03.166: W/ActivityManager(382): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b40820e0 u0 example.atlcitylimo/.Main t2 f}
07-24 07:28:03.216: W/ActivityManager(382): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b3fc3d40 u0 example.atlcitylimo/.Home t2 f}
07-24 07:28:04.626: I/Process(1358): Sending signal. PID: 1358 SIG: 9
07-24 07:28:04.646: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.646: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.656: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.656: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.656: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.656: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.656: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.656: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.676: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.676: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.726: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.726: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.776: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.776: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.776: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.776: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.786: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.786: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.786: E/SoundPool(382): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.786: W/AudioService(382): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-24 07:28:04.786: W/AudioService(382): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-24 07:28:04.826: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:28:05.106: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:28:05.236: I/Choreographer(382): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-24 07:28:05.356: I/ActivityManager(382): Process example.atlcitylimo (pid 1358) has died.
07-24 07:28:05.436: I/WindowState(382): WIN DEATH: Window{b408a908 u0 example.atlcitylimo/example.atlcitylimo.Main}
07-24 07:28:05.526: I/WindowState(382): WIN DEATH: Window{b3fdbc30 u0 Toast}
```

I have even added API key in my MANIFEST file . I have imported Google play library files and almost everything done. But its not running .The project directly crash. I have installed Google play service too. what can be done? Can anyone please help? its an emergency.

Comment: Post the logcat and Manifest.

Comment: 1. Post logcat output of the 'crash' (like people before me have said). 2. Post your Manifest, so we can check permissions (I suggest you remove your API key if you're worried about security).

Or at the very least, please copy and paste the error from logcat and any relevant code it relates to. At the moment it could be anything.

Comment: @rokesh_25 : what is `android:minSdkVersion` of your application

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="9"
 android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Comment: @rokesh_25 : change that to `12` otherwise you have to use `SupportFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Add this line to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem of implementing the map inside a fragment. So i made a FrameLayout layout file and used com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView instead of Mapfragment.
You can have a look [here](http://ucla.jamesyxu.com/?p=287)

It works with support libraries as well

Answer (score 0):

Your logcat says that it can't locate `MapFragment`

In your XML change change `android:name` to `class`

So your XML should look like this

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Comment: i did as u said but it didn't work..is there any other idea...?

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work ?? It should have removed atleast few errors so post your new logcat @rokesh_25